# Add a xib file to ad UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having this method where i'm creating a draggableView. I've beside this created a xib file, which i would like to add as a subview to this draggableView. How can i do this? The reason i want to do this is that i'm going to create a lot of xib files so the content will vary.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loadCards()

}

func createDraggableViewWithDataAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> DraggableView {
    let draggableView = DraggableView(frame: CGRectMake(12, 12, self.view.frame.width-24, self.view.frame.height-24-49-64))
    draggableView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    draggableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5).CGColor
    draggableView.delegate = self

    let subviewArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AdViewController", owner: self, options: nil)
    let mainView = subviewArray[0] as! UIView;
    draggableView.addSubview(mainView);


    return draggableView
}

func loadCards() -> Void {
    if exampleCardLabels.count > 0 {
        let numLoadedCardsCap = exampleCardLabels.count > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE ? MAX_BUFFER_SIZE : exampleCardLabels.count
        for var i = 0; i < exampleCardLabels.count; i++ {
            let newCard: DraggableView = self.createDraggableViewWithDataAtIndex(i)

            allCards.append(newCard)
            if i < numLoadedCardsCap {
                loadedCards.append(newCard)
            }
        }

        for var i = 0; i < loadedCards.count; i++ {
            if i > 0 {
                self.view.insertSubview(loadedCards[i], belowSubview: loadedCards[i - 1])
            } else {
                self.view.addSubview(loadedCards[i])
            }
            cardsLoadedIndex = cardsLoadedIndex + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Before:
[image]

After

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you add a custom view from xib

```
    let subviewArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyCustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
    let mainView = subviewArray[0] as! UIView;
    draggableView.addSubview(mainView);
```

Comment: Hmm i've tried it but look my updated question? when i add the code it seem to add it strangely ? the draggableView is the white. why dont it add it to that

Comment: can you please post your code where you add the xib? the black bit in your screenshot - is this the view you are adding?

Comment: yes the black bit is the xib file. yes i'm adding it now

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to add the mainView of your xib as a subView of your draggableView?
If yes just get the view from xib:

```
   let view = UINib(
            nibName: nibNamed,
            bundle: bundle
        ).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
```

And then add it as Subview to your draggrableView

```
draggableView.addSubview(view)
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm i've tried it but look my updated question? when i add the code it seem to add it strangely ? the draggableView is the white. why dont it add it to that